# Calculate working shift giving current datetime in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I need a sql script in sybase or at least ansi sql that giving the current datetime, i can get the current working shift.

- Working shift '1' begins at 08:00 and ends at 15:30
- Working shift '2' begins at 15:30 and ends at 23:00
- Working shift '3' begins at 23:00 and ends at 08:00AM of the next day

I am having trouble with the third shift, because of the change between one day and next day

```
SET  @FechaActual = convert(datetime, 'JUN 11 2015 11:00AM', 100) --getdate()

SET @HoraComienzoTurno1 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 08:00:00 AM")
SET @HoraFinTurno1 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:29:59 PM")
SET @HoraComienzoTurno2 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:30:00 PM")
SET @HoraFinTurno2 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 10:59:59 PM")
SET @HoraComienzoTurno3 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 11:00:00 PM")
SET @HoraFinTurno3 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 07:59:59 AM")

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno1 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno1
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS Turno, @FechaActual AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno2 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno2 
BEGIN
    SELECT 2 AS Turno, @FechaActual AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno3 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno3 
BEGIN
    SELECT 3 AS Turno, dateadd(dd, -1, @FechaActual) AS FechaActual
END
```

Comment: Which Sybase product are you using? Syntax can vary, so it's helpful to specify.

Comment: I'm using Sybase ASE 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no sybase here, then cannot try it.  I think what you need is [datepart function](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X71771.htm). This function only gets the hours, or minutes from the datetime value, then you will be able to easily check without thinking in days.

I did the following changes:

> - I changed the code to show how it works (maybe my spelling is not right)
> - I changed the last condition to be an OR, because it´s impossible for the last shift worker, to have an hour > 23 and < 9 at
>   the same time ;-)

Hope it may help you. (sorry if it doesn´t compile, but it´s a few years since I don´t play with sybase).

```
SET  @FechaActual = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime, 'JUN 11 2015 11:00AM', 100))

SET @HoraComienzoTurno1 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 08:00:00 AM"))
SET @HoraFinTurno1 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:29:59 PM"))
SET @HoraComienzoTurno2 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:30:00 PM"))
SET @HoraFinTurno2 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 10:59:59 PM"))
SET @HoraComienzoTurno3 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 11:00:00 PM"))
SET @HoraFinTurno3 = datepart("hhmi",convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 07:59:59 AM"))

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno1 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno1
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS Turno, @FechaActual AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno2 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno2 
BEGIN
    SELECT 2 AS Turno, @FechaActual AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno3 OR @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno3 
BEGIN
    SELECT 3 AS Turno, dateadd(dd, -1, @FechaActual) AS FechaActual
END
```

> **EDIT** Added "mi" to `datepart()` pattern, to manage also minutes

Comment: i just saw now you Have :30 shifts, then you will Need the mm too. I'll edit later to show it

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code, a bit messy but i'm trying to clean it up.

> - I had to substract a day to shift 3 start if actual date is past 12AM
> - Else add a day to shift 3 end

```
SET @FechaActual = getdate() --convert(datetime, 'JUN 12 2015 12:59:00AM', 100)
--Se toma la fecha actual, se convierte a varchar, se concatena la hora y se convierte a datetime nuevamente
SET @HoraComienzoTurno1 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 08:00:00 AM")
SET @HoraFinTurno1 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:29:59 PM")
SET @HoraComienzoTurno2 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 03:30:00 PM")
SET @HoraFinTurno2 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 10:59:59 PM")

--Si son pasada las 12:00AM del turno 3, la fecha de comienzo de turno debe ser un dia antes, en caso contrario el fin de turno debe ser al dia siguiente
IF @FechaActual >= convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 12:00:00 AM") AND @FechaActual <= convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 07:59:59 AM")
BEGIN

        SET @FechaActualTurno3 = dateadd(dd, -1, @FechaActual)
        SET @HoraComienzoTurno3 = dateadd(dd, -1, convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 11:00:00 PM"))
        SET @HoraFinTurno3 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 07:59:59 AM")
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        SET @FechaActualTurno3 = @FechaActual
        SET @HoraComienzoTurno3 = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 11:00:00 PM")
        SET @HoraFinTurno3 = dateadd(dd, 1, convert(datetime,convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 101) + " 07:59:59 AM"))
END

--Condiciones
IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno1 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno1
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS Turno, convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 103) AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno2 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno2 
BEGIN
    SELECT 2 AS Turno, convert(varchar, @FechaActual, 103) AS FechaActual
END

IF @FechaActual >= @HoraComienzoTurno3 AND @FechaActual <= @HoraFinTurno3 
BEGIN
    SELECT 3 AS Turno, convert(varchar, @FechaActualTurno3, 103) AS FechaActual
END
```